# Unexpected behavior in JAVA

Tags: java

[image]

I can't understand this!! Please help

```
for (int i = fromSuraIndex; i <= toSuraIndex; i++) {
        if (i == toSuraIndex && toCharIndex == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (i > fromSuraIndex) {
            currentWordIndexInSura = 0;
            suraGenaricWordIndexMap.put(fromSuraIndex,currentWordIndexInSura - words.size());
        }
}
```

The problem occurs in the first loop , while "fromSuraIndex" equal "i" equal 1, Why the debugger enter the IF block

Comment: Please post the relevant code and error as text instead of as an image. Also, please try to explain the problem better.

Comment: Make sure your debugger and runtime class files are in sync.

Comment: I saved all files, sync them, and clean / rebuild the project, the problem is still existing

Comment: @JustMe plz add small description about your problem .edit your question

Comment: Are both variables of the same int type? If your fromSuraIndex is a double, for example, it will promote variable i to doubleand in that case it's not guaranteed that fromSuraIndex is exactly the same as i

Answer (score 0):

This means that it won't enter to if block that you showed only for the first step of the loop where 'i' will have its initial value which is 'fromSuraIndex'. When 'i' value is incremented then it qualifies the if statement.

Comment: The problem occurs in the first loop , while "fromSuraIndex" equal "i" equal 1, Why the debugger enter the IF block

Comment: As far as I know it might happen only if you add some piece of code but forget to restart you application server and try to debug it. So the application server has no idea about the new code and therefore you can end up seeing debugger in even nonsense places like that you showed..

Comment: I saved all files, sync them, and clean / rebuild the project, the problem is still existing, I am a developer for 18 years ago,